# putting 24/7 live radio on website

Tags: streaming, radio

I am trying to figure out how to put a live radio player in a website, for broadcasting from my home studio. I also want to open it up so other people can also broadcast to the website from their homes with minimal setup (maybe through skype?). Not massive amounts of people - it will be just a friends thing to start with. Other features I'd like to implement are being able to switch between live broadcast mode and playing files hosted on the server (or elsewhere, e.g Soundcloud), as well as live broadcasts being automatically recorded and made available for downloading.

I don't know if there's anything out there that does all of that, even though it seems a fairly standard set of requirements, but if there isn't I'd also like to ask for suggestions of how I could piece all this together, since I've no idea how live audio works!
If there really is nothing like that, maybe I could start an open source project and make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Lithiumhosting is a great provider of streaming audio over the internet. They are pretty cheap too. I use their webservers and I am very pleased with their service!

As to what softwares you should use. It depends on how much money you are willing to put into it. A good way of doing it would be to use an analog mixing board and send the audio into the streaming computer. But you could as well do it on the computer. Again, it depends on how much money you are willing to put into it. Go to Google and study each software in depth. There are dozens of them.

Good luck!

Comment: lithiumhosting looks great, I will definitely give that a try!
About what software to use, I can figure that out, I'll do it quite low-key and maybe if I feel like it eventually patch my own sollution together. Soundboards are a definite must!